# Design a polymorphic class hierarchy without virtual destructor

Tags: c++, performance, polymorphism, hierarchy, virtual-destructor

I find myself in a situation that calls for rapid instantiation and deletion of many objects, which ends up taking a lot of CPU and user time, so I need to shave off as much as possible from that process. I do realize a non-virtual destructor will not be a significant gain, but it will still save a few percent of the time, and together with a few other optimizations will stack into a tangible improvement from a user's perspective.

I know that the rule of thumb is that in such polymorphic hierarchies it is recommended practice to begin with making the destructor virtual, so that when objects are deleted the appropriate code is ran to do all the necessary clean-up.

But what if it didn't matter which destructor will be called? What if all the subclass specific dynamic data that needs collecting is packed and instantiated in the specific constructor to a pointer dedicated for that purpose in the "very-base-class"? In this case, every object can instantiate and access it specific plus inherited dynamic data through the pointer which is "collected" by the base class destructor which can be inlined, so regardless of its actually content and size that dynamic memory will be de-allocated by the OS, which only needs the address and does not care about size, so no memory leaks, no overhead from virtual calls.

So, does this sound like a good idea? Any potential pitfalls?

EDIT: A simple test:

```
class A {
  public:
  ~A() {cout << "A" << endl; }
};

class B : public A {
  public:
  ~B() {cout << "B" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
   A * a = new A;
   A * b = new B;
   B * br = new B;

   delete a;
   delete b;
   delete br;

   return 0;
}
```

output:

```
A
A
B
A
```

So regardless of what pointer is deleted, the base class destructor which collects all memory is called no matter what. Is there possibility for anything else to happen? If so when and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very big pitfall, yes - undefined behavior. The following code exhibits it:

```
struct A
{};
struct B : A
{};

//....
A* a = new B;
delete a;
```

Deleting a base class pointer that points to a derived class leads to UB if the base class doesn't have a `virtual` destructor. If you plan on doing this, you need the `virtual` destructor.

Comment: I don't understand, what I think will happen is whatever destructor is called (e.g. from whatever type of pointer), it will either be that of the bottom base class or that of one derived from it that will nest the base class destructor. Or is this not correct?

Comment: @ddriver no, it's not correct. The rules of the language explicitly say that you need a virtual destructor if you run into the above scenario.

Comment: @ddriver: if you call `delete` on an `A` pointer that is actually pointing at an instance of `B`, the `B` destructor **will not** be called unless the `A` destructor is `virtual`. Otherwise, only the `A` destructor will be called, and the `B` object will not be fully destructed correctly.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - the whole idea is to make the entire hierarchy design so that it doesn't matter which destructor is called as long as the base class destructor gets called. No other destructor but that of the base class actually does anything.

Comment: @ddriver you're missing the point. Regardless of what the code you posted shows, it has undefined behavior. It could very well just crash next time, it could leak memory, etc.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - so the standard does not state something like "without virtual destructor, the destructor for the pointer type used to do the deletion is called". But last night I did some automated testing, and after testing a few hundred billion times with a procedurally generated hierarchy of a few thousand of classes it seems that "it could very well crash next time" is about as probable as being eaten by a great white shark the same day I win the lottery while Earth gets struck by a life eradicating meteor.

Comment: Ergo it does seem to be pretty reliable despite the lack of concrete stance in the standard on that subject. Thus my question - when and why it could possibly break.

Comment: @ddriver that could also happen, yes. That's what undefined behavior means.

Comment: @ddriver as to when and why it could break - at any time and because it can break.

Comment: @ddriver try creating an array of pointers with `new*` and see if that leaks.